# Write a query that change according to the variable

Tags: jquery, typescript, postgresql, api

I would like to make a query that change depending of a JSON.

On the JSON there is the name of the column and then the value such as:

```
"siret": "21157890",
"name":"Toto",
"address": "random address",
"city": "Paris"
```

I'm using PostgreSQL and Typescript.

Right now this is working but it is only for specific column

```
await db.query(`
    INSERT INTO user_company_fk (name, address)
    VALUES ($1, $2)
    `, [param.name, param.address]);
```

But if the user just send name I don't want to update the address.

Or if he send other column, I want to update the other column.

Comment: I'm not good in typescript but I can give you idea in php

Comment: Yeah sure maybe it will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving example in php. Convert it as you need in typescript.
you can convert `json to array` then use the for loop on that array. Suppose you sent siret and name then your array will be

```
$arr = ['siret' => '21157890', 'name' => 'xyz'];
$str1 = '';
$valStr = '';
$array1 = [];
$count = 1;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  $str1 .= $key. ', ';  // concatenate the string $key has siret
  $valStr .= '$'.$count. ', ';  // to use $1, $2, $3 etc
  $array1[] = $arr[$key]; // $value has 21157890
}
$str1 = rtim( $str1 , ', '); // remove the last comma from string
$valStr = rtim( $valStr , ', ');
```

Now create query like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_company_fk (" . $str1 . ") VALUES(" . $valStr . ")";

await db.query($sql, $array1);
```

The code sample is in php but i think It can help you. If it work for you, you can edit here. I will approve your code

Comment: I think this would work ! i will post the update tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I re-use the code of Karnal-YK, adapted it for TypeScript and for an UPDATE to a table

```
let field = '';
const valueArray:string[] = [];
let count = 1;
let queryStr = '';
try {
    Object.entries(body).forEach((entry) => {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      field += key + ' = $' + count.toString() + ', ';
      valueArray[count - 1] = value as string; // array start at 0
      count += 1;
    });
    field = field.slice(0, -2); // remove ', ' for the last one
    queryStr = 'UPDATE companies SET ' + field + ' WHERE id = ' + companyId;
    const result = await db.query(queryStr, valueArray);
```